# How can I trigger ZF2 HTML 5 Validation?

Tags: php, html, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm using a custom button to submit my forms but want to take advantage of the HTML 5 validation.  How can I trigger this validation prior to posting the data.  I have two separate forms and would like to check the validation on both.

I see that the button has to reside in the form (prior to the close tag) in order for the validation to be triggered.  Was wondering if there was a best practice is to do this?

This triggers the validation when added inside the form

```
<form>
...
 <button id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-warning" value="Submit" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have one submit button for two forms.

Thanks,
M

Comment: If you are wanting to use html attributes to accomplish client-side validation (HTML5 validaton) prior to the submission of the form you might want to look at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp for all the attributes you can use. Note: This should not be used as a substitute to server side filtering/validation however, simply an enhancement to client side usability.